# How to setup UPnP Remote Acess service?

Tags: android, ios, remote-access, upnp

I am setting up an app in which I have to **remotely operate** the device (switch) from the other network.From my studies I came to know that it can be done using **UPnP**.I have implemented the code for local network which is able to operate the device on the same network.But when I change the network I am unable to do so.I went through the [UPnP forum pdf](http://www.upnp.org/resources/whitepapers/UPnPRemoteAccessWhitePaper_2012.pdf) and got the theoretical idea of Remote Access implementation.But I didn't get any sample code for the same in any programming language.Is there any sample code for this or at least can somebody suggest me how can I achieve this?